# The page can not be displayed. 10060 connection timeout

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, iis

My query needs more than 20 minutes to run and export the result in excel. I get the output for top 10 records (query taking time is low), but the error page is displayed for long run query.

I set `sqlcommand.CommandTimeout=0` also.

```
IIS version 7.0 ,
Sql server 2008 R2
```

**Error:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzKd.png]

Comment: I did not get any problems in local server

Comment: Did you check with your network admin if there are limits on open network sessions ?  Try exporting the data to a local file on the database server, and then retrieve the file once it's done.

Comment: in my system no admin rights. it's working on admin rights system. ok i will do as per your instruction

Comment: Sorry it's not working. I get that error page when i retrieve the data from sql. It's working in admin rights system. In my system no admin rights but i get result for top 10 records but i did not get result for all records. I don't know what was that problem

Comment: If you try with a smaller data set - just 10 records. Do you still get the error ?  If not, try and split the record set into smaller sets. And then combine locally the files.

Comment: Please tell me why it's not coming for larger records. Error page displayed before getting result from sql. Need to set anything in iis or sql server or c# ?

Comment: From what you;re describing, it's most likely a network limitition regarding time/out of sessions. See link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811087 which most likely matches your errors.  What I gave you is a possible work-around.

Comment: Thank you. It's proxy problem only. I removed proxy, it's working.